# Cant find file to patch, but file exists

Tags: php, composer-php, patch

I am using cweagans/composer-patches to patch files via composer.
I am trying to apply a patch to 2 files, however it comes up with this error:
`error: vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/CompositeRepository.php : No such file or directory`  which is the file I am trying to patch. The problem is, if I run `nano vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/CompositeRepository.php` I can open up the file no problem, so the file exists. I can't figure out how to get this to work, or why it can't open the file that exists where it says it doesn't exist.

Here is the patch file:

```
--- vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php    2021-04-27 04:11:08.000000000 -0700
+++ vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php    2022-11-10 10:51:04.206095616 -0800
@@ -274,7 +274,7 @@
      *
      * @return int Number of packages
      */
-    public function count()
+    public function count(): int
     {
         if (null === $this->packages) {
             $this->initialize();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to update `composer/composer`, as the return type has been added there some months ago?

Comment: Also `vendor/composer/composer/src/` looks so fishy to me. Some of the dependencies is obviously messing with your tooling (`composer`) by requiring it as a library - which is technical possible but ... -  then requires the patching composer plugin (tooling, **not** library) to patch the library. Well this pretty much sounds like asking for trouble IMHO. Next to tooling upgrade, perhaps as well consider to overhaul the project composer configuration for a step forward.

Comment: sorry, for my lengthy comment without commenting on the actual error message: it looks like that the patch command is operating on a different base directory / directory base. Consider to patch with `git(1)` directly, it is likely available, otherwise standard `patch(1)` should do it, too. IIRC cweagans/composer-patches invokes `patch(1)` .

Answer (score -1):

It would be useful to see part of the composer code with patch description. Perhaps instead of

```
--- vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/...
+++ vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/...
```

should be

```
--- a/src/Composer/Repository/...
+++ b/src/Composer/Repository/...
```

and inside composer.json

```json
"extra": {
    "patches": {
        "composer/composer": {
            "Description info": "path/to/patch/file.patch"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Please share more details. How does this answer the given problem?

Comment: Wow, really? I gave quite accurate advice on what needs to be changed to solve the problem via cweagans/composer-patches. Please share more details why does this answer seem doubtful to you?) Or wait for the opinion of the one who asked the question

Comment: "Perhaps" does not sound like an answer to me. What do you mean by "composer code with patch description"?

Comment: "Perhaps" is "perhaps", because who knows? Huh? Also in my answer, I provided that part of the composer.json which interested me. Because when using cweagans/composer-patches, it is necessary not only to correctly compile the patch relative to the vendor library, but also to correctly describe it.  Are you still skeptical about this answer?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer such that others can learn from it